# How to solve this partial equation : $(\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial y})*(f(x,y))^2 = \frac{1}3$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

[image]

given the folowing change of variable $(u,v)=g(x,y)=(\frac{1}2(x+y),\frac{1}2(x-y))$ , How do I solve the equation ?
Here is my try:
let $F(u,v)=(f\circ g^{-1}) (u,v)$ so $(F\circ g)(x,y)=f(x,y)$ we'll have then: $$(\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial x},\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial y}) =(\frac{1}2(\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial v}),\frac{1}2(\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial v}))$$
I then replaced in the equation with the values of $\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial x} and \frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial y}$
I found: $$\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial v}*(F(u,v))^2 = \frac{1}3$$
From here I dont' know how to continue, any help please ?

Comment: Rewrite the last equation as $$\frac{\partial{(F(u,v)^3)}}{\partial v} = 1$$

Comment: Then how do i continue in this case F(u,v) is equal to some function H(u,v) that I can't define. I always find when solving partial equations : $\frac{\partial{F(u,v)}}{\partial v}  = 0 $ so this implies F(u,v) is equal to some function H(u)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: after rewriting $$\frac{\partial{(F(u,v)^3)}}{\partial v} = 1$$ and setting $H(u,v)=F(u,v)^3$ we integrate and obtain $H(u,v)=v+c(u)$. Thus, $F(u,v)=\sqrt[3]{v+c(u)}$.